# How to apply Maximum likelihood estimator on RGB values in MATLAB using predefined function?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file that consists `3 columns and N rows` of RGB values [[See Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsZR4.png)] of a particular region of a image. I am trying to use the `mle` function that is **predefined** in matlab but not able to do it.

These are the possible methods that can be used as shown on matlab website but **I don't know how and which one to implement** with RGB values.

```
phat = mle(data)
phat = mle(data,'distribution',dist)
phat = mle(data,'pdf',pdf,'start',start)
phat = mle(data,'pdf',pdf,'start',start,'cdf',cdf)
phat = mle(data,'logpdf',logpdf,'start',start)
phat = mle(data,'logpdf',logpdf,'start',start,'logsf',logsf)
phat = mle(data,'nloglf',nloglf,'start',start)
phat = mle(___,Name,Value)
[phat,pci] = mle(___)
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what MLE is? `data` must be a vector for the `mle` function.

Comment: @David Sorry. I am new to Matlab. Can you tell me a possible way of finding mle of rgb values.

Comment: Is there a way to convert them to vector

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so writing as an answer.
You can read your rgb data into an nx3 matrix.
Since the mle function needs a vector of 1 dimensional values, from what I understand, one way to go ahead would be to average the r,g and b values and get a mean vector of size nx1.(you will have to evaluate if this serves your purpose)
Then pass it to the mle function, as

```
phat = mle(data);
```

IF you think your data will be fit by an unskewed normal distribution function. Otherwise you can use the form

```
phat = mle(data,'distribution',dist);
```

and provide the distribution yourself or look up and choose from some of matlab's provided distributions, for example, 'burr'. 
You can also probably view the distribution using a histogram to see what the distribution looks like first.
http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/mle.html

Comment: can u please give an example of how this can be done with some sample data. Thanks.